# Getting Error While Using HTTP on Mule ESB canvas

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I am just trying to write a hello world application with help of below video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AUfUMXwzu24 
I have just used HTTP from pallet and it is giving me below error

**"Required attribute config-ref is not defined in listener"**

 in Anypoint studio it is showing error in below line 
<http:listener config-ref="" path="" doc:name="HTTP"/>
 I am using version 5.1.0 of Anypoint studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an `http:listener-config` element, like for example:

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
```

See: https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/HTTP+Listener+Connector

Comment: Ah! thanks a ton. I am just a beginner following the tutorial and it wasn't mentioned their.
working fine now!